# Set R's "Crash Dump" location in Windows

Tags: r, windows

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with almost 0 free space on its C:. I've installed R and RStudio to the E:\, which has plenty of space.

For some reason Crash Dump file keep appearing in my user Program Data folder on the C:. This makes the drive literally hit 0kb and causes problems until I go delete them.

I haven't been able to determine how to set this behavior in R or RStudio. What controls the location where these files are created (or how can I disable them)?

Comment: The location is unlikely to be configurable. Error reporting needs to be robust, and writing to a known location, that's set up to be writable for the current user is one ingredient to make it robust.